# how to get posts ids inside pre_get_posts filter?

Tags: posts, wp-query, pre-get-posts, exclude

I'm trying to do these one:
On the home (front page) i have multiple posts loops.
I need posts to not repeat across these loops ( i.e if post was shown in 1-st loop it should never appear in 2-nd or 3-rd and so on ).

I'v come up with these ( lower ), but my solution requires me to do query 2 times for each loop ( so if i have 3 loops i'll do 6 db requests ) witch is kind of bad.

So my question is: Can i get posts ids inside `pre_get_posts` filter.

My code so far:

```
/** Hack to exclude repeating of posts */
if( ! function_exists( 'jews_exclude_shown_posts' ) ) {
    function jews_exclude_shown_posts( $query ) {
        if( is_admin() ) return $query;

        if( $query->is_main_query() ) {
            $GLOBALS['jews_exclude'] = array();
        } elseif (
            false !== $query->query_vars['jews_exclude'] &&
            (
                null === $query->query_vars['post_type']
                || ( is_array( $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) && in_array( 'post', $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) )
                || 'post' === $query->query_vars['post_type']
            )
        ) {
            if( ! empty( $GLOBALS['jews_exclude'] ) ) {
                $query->set('post__not_in', $GLOBALS['jews_exclude']);
            }
            $args = $query->query;
            $args['jews_exclude'] = false;
            $execute = new WP_query( $args );//here i do dubble query witch i dont't want to do
            if( $execute->have_posts() ) {
                foreach( $execute->posts as $ex )
                    $GLOBALS['jews_exclude'][ $ex->ID ] = $ex->ID;
            }
        }
        return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'jews_exclude_shown_posts' );
```

Comment: pre_get_posts fires pre getting the posts. At that point you haven't got the posts so you can't see the IDs.

Answer (score 1):

We could try to use the `the_posts` filter, that's applied on the queried posts, if the  `suppress_filters` query variable is false, to collect relevant post IDs.

We can then use the `pre_get_posts` hook, in each query, to exclude the **accumulated** array of post IDs.

Here's a schema example for the process:

```
// Main query
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$wp_query->posts filtered and collected post IDs [1,2] from the 'post' post type

// Sub query #1
$q1 = new WP_Query( [ 'wpse_exclude' => true, ... ] );
pre_get_posts excludes accumulated [1,2]
$q1->posts filtered and collected [3,4] 

// Sub query #2
$q2 = new WP_Query( [ 'wpse_exclude' => true, ... ] );
pre_get_posts excludes accumulated [1,2,3,4]
$q2->posts filtered and collected  [5,6]

// Sub query #3
$q3 = new WP_Query( $args );
No exclusion because 'wpse_exclude' argument is missing
$q3->posts filtered and collected [7]

// Sub query #4
$q4 = new WP_Query( [ 'wpse_exclude' => true, ... ] );
pre_get_posts excludes accumulated [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
$q4->posts filtered and collected [8,9]
```

Here are possible building blocks for a demo class that could help with that:

The `init()` method:

```
public function init( $collect_post_type = 'post' )
{
    // Collect post IDs
    add_filter( 'the_posts', [ $this, 'the_posts' ] );

    // Exclude accumulated post IDs in queries
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', [ $this, 'pre_get_posts' ] );

    // Initialize accumulated post IDs for exclusion
    $this->exclude_pids = [];

    // Collect post IDs only from this post type
    $this->collect_post_type = $collect_post_type;
}
```

The `pre_get_posts()` method:

```
public function pre_get_posts( \WP_Query $q )
{
    if( 
        $q->is_home()                 // Target the home page
        && $q->get( 'wpse_exclude' )  // Target queries with wpse_exclude set as true
     // && ... etc
    ) {     
        // Exclude accumulated set of post IDs
        if( ! empty( $this->exclude_pids ) )
            $q->set( 'post__not_in', $this->exclude_pids );
    }
}
```

Here we should also consider preserving any previous `post__not_in` arguments.

The `the_posts()` method:

```
public function the_posts( array $posts )
{
    // Collect post IDs from 'post' post type and merge to the $pids array
    $this->exclude_pids = array_merge( 
        $this->exclude_pids , 
        (array) wp_filter_object_list( 
            $posts,
            [ 'post_type' => $this->collect_post_type ], 
            'AND', 
            'ID' 
        )  
    );

    return $posts;
}
```

Hope you can adjust this to your needs.